# add colorbox to dynamicly created item with url content

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to add a colorbox to a dynamicly created object, it works on the first click but won't open after the second one, I'm not sure what to do. I'm wondering if I'm not closing the colorbox somehow or if its hanging in the background...

```
    $(".login").live('click', function(){
    $.fn.colorbox({href:"http://ww.website/Login.html", open:true});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".login").live('click', function(){
   $.colorbox({ href:'http://threadless.com', iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%" });
});
```

OR

```
content.on('click', '.login', function(){
   $.colorbox({ href:'http://threadless.com', iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%" });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F5jGQ/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be calling:

```
$(".login").live('click', function(){
     $.colorbox({href:"http://ww.website/Login.html", open:true});
});
```